# SQL - List matching results next to each other

Tags: sql, filtered

I am trying to get matching results to list next to each other based on the primary key column and the ones that don't match be either blank or N/A.

The query I am using but doesn't work since the results from the initial table are just repeating themselves. Applying "distinct" doesn't work on any of the columns as well for me.

Sample QUERY:

```
IF EXISTS   (
            SELECT *
            FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
            WHERE id = Object_id(N'tempdb..#TABLE_A')
            )
        BEGIN
            DROP TABLE #TABLE_A
        END

IF EXISTS   (
            SELECT *
            FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
            WHERE id = Object_id(N'tempdb..#TABLE_B')
            )
        BEGIN
            DROP TABLE #TABLE_B
        END

select Animal_1, Qty_1
    into #TABLE_A
from TABLE_AA
    
select Animal_2, SUM(Qty_2) 
    into #TABLE_B
from TABLE_BB 
group by Animal_2


select  
        Animal_1, 
        Qty_1,
        Animal_2, 
        Qty_2 
from #TABLE_A, #TABLE_B
```

RESULTS

[image]

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN`!

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: try union but not union all, on left join and right join

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
select  
        Animal_1,  Qty_1, Animal_2, Qty_2 
from #TABLE_A left join #TABLE_B
ON Animal_1=Animal_2
Union
select  
        Animal_1,  Qty_1, Animal_2, Qty_2 
from #TABLE_A Right join #TABLE_B
ON Animal_1=Animal_2
```